# I've gotten some errors when i tried to burn it on cd, whats wrong?

Tags: burning

I've downloaded Ubuntu so many times and the ISO image won't burn properly on CD, it returns me an error.

I've gotten some errors when I tried to burn it on CD, whats wrong? I've changed the CD media and the same error still appears. What do I do?

Comment: What burning program are you using

Comment: maybe you could post the error message?

Comment: try to reduce the speed when you are burning the iso.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a problem with your CD writer. Try burning the disk on a different drive or computer. Also, the problem might be the software you are using, so use different software if you can too.